# Suprema SDK with Visual FoxPro

Tags: c#, .net, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I got the BioMini scanner from [Suprema](http://www.supremainc.com/eng/product/pc_22.php?mark=33), they provided a wrapped Dll made with C#, they also provide example using: VB6, VB.net, JAVA en C#, but they do not provide Visual FoxPro examples, and the Dll they provide cannot be use from Visual FoxPro, I have tried using like a COM or win32 DLL, but it just don't work, it look like they don't provide the "InteropServices" option to use it with language like FoxPro.

They explain some in here: http://www.supremainc.com/eng/images/product/biominisdk_img01.gif

I had a send an email to the support guide from Suprema, a month ago with not answer.
Any help will be fully appreciate.

Thanks,
Oscar

Comment: You should be able to make this work by writing a wrapper DLL in C# and doing whatever is required to expose a COM interface from the wrapper DLL to FoxPro

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy!! 
that I'm doing.